# Spring Boot : execute a job at a particular Date entered by the user

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduling

Im trying to manage scheduled tasks using spring boot. I want to execute my job only one time at a particular date ( specified by the user ). 
Here is my Job :

```
@Component
public class JobScheduler{

    @Autowired
    JobController controller;
    // Retrieving the Date entered by the user
    controller.getDateForExecution();  // 2016/05/24 10:00 for example

    @Scheduled(???)
    public void performJob() throws Exception {
        controller.doSomething();
    }
```

There are multiple options for Scheduled annotation such as fixedDelay, fixedRate, initialDelay, cron ... but none of these can accept a Date.
So, how can i execute my method at the specified Date dynamically ( ie depending on the Date insered ) ?

Ps : The method can be executed more than once if the user enter two or more Dates ..

Answer (score 2):

Spring has the TaskScheduler abstraction that you can use: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler

It has a method to schedule execution of a `Runnable` at a certain `Date`:

```
ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime);
```

A little off-topic maybe: If `JobController` is a Spring `Controller` (or `RestController`), I would not autowire it into the `JobScheduler`. I would inverse it and inject the `JobScheduler` into the `JobController`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know this is a very old questions but for future references, here's the answer:

You can use cron property, which gives much more control over the scheduling of a task. It lets us define the seconds, minutes ,and hours the task runs at but can go even further and specify even the years that a task will run in.

Below is a breakdown of the components that build a cron expression.

- Seconds can have values 0-59 or the special characters , - * / .
- Minutes can have values 0-59 or the special characters , - * / .
- Hours can have values 0-59 or the special characters , - * / .
- Day of month can have values 1-31 or the special characters , - * ? / L W C .
- Month can have values 1-12, JAN-DEC or the special characters , - * / .
- Day of week can have values 1-7, SUN-SAT or the special characters , - * ? / L C # .
- Year can be empty, have values 1970-2099 or the special characters , - * / .

Just for some extra clarity, I have combined the breakdown into an expression consisting of the field labels.

@Scheduled(cron = "[Seconds] [Minutes] [Hours] [Day of month] [Month] [Day of week] [Year]")

For more you can follow this article: https://dzone.com/articles/running-on-time-with-springs-scheduled-tasks